# Register for memory warning notification in standalone SDK

Tags: ios, memory, sdk

I am developing an SDK for iOS, which requires implementing App to run in background all the time. There may be some cases when iOS generates low warning notification. I want to register for memory warning notification in my SDK (rather than in the implementing app) so that I can free up memory accordingly.

Is it possible to do so? If Yes can anyone please share some code on how to register for observer/notification for low memory in a standalone SDK.

P.S. My plan B for handling this situation would be providing an interface in my SDK, so that implementing App can forwarding me memory warning notification from it's AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object can register for the memory warning notification (`UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`), the same way you'd register for any notification, using `NSNotificationCenter`. Choose an appropriate object within your SDK and have it listen for, and respond to, the notification.